# Sending a private message on YouTube. Autofill subject and body

Tags: javascript, email, google-chrome-extension, youtube, firefox-addon

I am working on an extension for YouTube. I would like to offer the user a button that takes the user to the compose private message page. YouTube uses a user ID parameter to autofill the user name as follows:

http://www.youtube.com/inbox?to_user_ext_ids=[SOMEID]&action_compose=1

I would like to know if it is possible to add a subject parameter to autofill the subject field as you would with a standard email.

http://www.youtube.com/inbox?to_user_ext_ids=[SOMEID]&action_compose=1**&subject=[SOMESUBJECT]**

The above doesn't work. Does anyone know if such a parameter exists?

Comment: I don't know if such a parameter exists, but you can always inject a content script to fill it for you. (You have to ask for the apropriate permission, of course.)

Comment: Oh yes of course. I should have thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: This is of course possible. Do you still need help? You just look at the nsIHTTPChannel and take the parameters from there. If you're still working on this let me know and I'll write the snippet.